# detecting three presses of power button

Tags: android

I'm new in Android. I'm trying to make an app that will run in background and detect three rapid presses of the power button. I've looked up a lot, but could not clear my confusion. can anyone please give me some suggestion? TIA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declare the static variable outside the `onKeyDown` and increment variable inside the `onKeyDown` and return if the value is equal to 3 and at the end again equal the static variable equal to 0;

```
static int i=0;
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if (event.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_POWER) {
       i++;
        if(i==3){
    //do something

//at the end again i=0;
        }

    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could listen for every press of the power button, then in your listener you could

- measure how many presses you have just made up to this point
- measure the time between your current press and your last press
- if your time interval is right (say 200 ms) then increment your n_presses and do whatever you want after you reach 3 presses (e.g. create a super event and send it to a thread to process it)