# How to detect device power button press twice in android programmatically

Tags: android

I am making an android application which needs to detect the event of device power button press twice/thrice & send an SMS in the background. The listener should run in the background (i.e even if my app is not open, it should detect the keypress event and act accordingly).

Below is my tried code which is not working...

My Code:

```
public class MyBroadCastReciever extends BroadcastReceiver {

     int Count=0;

     @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF)) {
               Count++;
               if(Count==2){
                  //Send SMS code..
                 }


            } else if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON)) {
                 //This is for screen ON option.
            }
        }
```

Manifest file:

```
  <application
       android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
       android:label="@string/app_name"
       android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >


    <receiver android:name=".MyBroadCastReciever" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SCREEN_OFF" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SCREEN_ON" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
</application>
```

Comment: I guess you'll never have 2 straight screen off or on, it will be always alternated.

Comment: @PedroLobito thats ok.but its not detecting even any one(ON/OFF)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Detect on/off Key Press Android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6848518/detect-on-off-key-press-android)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because OP is saying `code not working` rather than giving the complete part of code and trying to help himself/volunteers .

Comment: @sanjay how are you counting number of press of power button by using below code?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Here's the code I'm using to detect if the user is present, screen on/off.

`AndroidManifest.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.userpresent"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="21" />


    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.userpresent.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

            <service android:name="com.example.userpresent.LockService" >
                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
                </intent-filter>
            </service>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

`MainActivity.java`

```
package com.example.userpresent;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        startService(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), LockService.class));
    }
}
```

`LockService.java`

```
package com.example.userpresent;

import android.app.Service;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.os.Binder;
import android.os.IBinder;

public class LockService extends Service {

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        final IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON);
        filter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF);
        filter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_USER_PRESENT);
        final BroadcastReceiver mReceiver = new ScreenReceiver();
        registerReceiver(mReceiver, filter);
        return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
    }
    public class LocalBinder extends Binder {
        LockService getService() {
            return LockService.this;
        }
    }
}
```

`ScreenReceiver.java`

```
package com.example.userpresent;

import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.util.Log;

public class ScreenReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    public static boolean wasScreenOn = true;

    @Override
    public void onReceive(final Context context, final Intent intent) {
    Log.e("LOB","onReceive");
        if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF)) {
            // do whatever you need to do here
            wasScreenOn = false;
            Log.e("LOB","wasScreenOn"+wasScreenOn);
        } else if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON)) {
            // and do whatever you need to do here
            wasScreenOn = true;

        } else if(intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_USER_PRESENT)){
            Log.e("LOB","userpresent");
            Log.e("LOB","wasScreenOn"+wasScreenOn);
            String url = "http://www.stackoverflow.com";
            Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            i.setData(Uri.parse(url)); 
            context.startActivity(i); 
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks man. Its working fine.But like wise, How could i track long press of power button from above code.

Comment: You're welcome, take a look at this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/10365166/797495

Comment: That link is fine. But I donno where i can use that code(onKeyLongPress..)? Should it comes on onStartCommand method on LockService.java class?

Comment: To use that code you don't need anything from my answer, just put that right before the last `}` on your class.

Comment: If i use that onLongPress method just last } on my mainActivity., It works only when the app is active. If im out of my app., it will not work. thats y i ask how could i use that code on service?

Comment: `GestureDetector.OnGestureListener` is your friend

[Interface / GestureDetector.OnGestureListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/GestureDetector.OnGestureListener.html)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Lemme try & get you.

Comment: also, try using the code of the other answer inside  service and see if it works.

Comment: @PedroLobito I doubt How `OnGestureListener` is helpful here ? Since OP is asking about the pressing of power button nothing to do with screen Gestures

Comment: @Pedro Lobito but it does not work when we kill the app from background

Comment: I tried This Code but it's not working pls Help. When I long press the power button I cannot detect this using the Above code.

Answer (score 7):

This is something I have done,

`short description` : You just have to detect when the screen `turn off` and `turns on` calculate the time difference between them, if its less than 4 seconds(`in my case`) send the message else don't .

> P.S- You can change the intervals of `pressing of power buttons`.

use it in your `BroadcastReceiver`:

```
@Override
public void onReceive(final Context context, final Intent intent) {
 cntx = context;
 vibe = (Vibrator) context.getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
 Log.v("onReceive", "Power button is pressed.");
 if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF)) {
  a = System.currentTimeMillis();
  seconds_screenoff = a;
  OLD_TIME = seconds_screenoff;
  OFF_SCREEN = true;

  new CountDownTimer(5000, 200) {

   public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {


    if (ON_SCREEN) {
     if (seconds_screenon != 0 && seconds_screenoff != 0) {

      actual_diff = cal_diff(seconds_screenon, seconds_screenoff);
      if (actual_diff <= 4000) {
       sent_msg = true;
       if (sent_msg) {

        Toast.makeText(cntx, "POWER BUTTON CLICKED 2 TIMES", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        vibe.vibrate(100);
        seconds_screenon = 0 L;
        seconds_screenoff = 0 L;
        sent_msg = false;

       }
      } else {
       seconds_screenon = 0 L;
       seconds_screenoff = 0 L;

      }
     }
    }
   }

   public void onFinish() {

    seconds_screenoff = 0 L;
   }
  }.start();



 } else if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON)) {
  a = System.currentTimeMillis();
  seconds_screenon = a;
  OLD_TIME = seconds_screenoff;

  new CountDownTimer(5000, 200) {

   public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
    if (OFF_SCREEN) {
     if (seconds_screenon != 0 && seconds_screenoff != 0) {
      actual_diff = cal_diff(seconds_screenon, seconds_screenoff);
      if (actual_diff <= 4000) {
       sent_msg = true;
       if (sent_msg) {

        Toast.makeText(cntx, "POWER BUTTON CLICKED 2 TIMES", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        vibe.vibrate(100);
        seconds_screenon = 0 L;
        seconds_screenoff = 0 L;
        sent_msg = false;



       }
      } else {
       seconds_screenon = 0 L;
       seconds_screenoff = 0 L;

      }
     }
    }

   }

   public void onFinish() {

    seconds_screenon = 0 L;
   }
  }.start();



 }
}

private long cal_diff(long seconds_screenon2, long seconds_screenoff2) {
 if (seconds_screenon2 >= seconds_screenoff2) {
  diffrence = (seconds_screenon2) - (seconds_screenoff2);
  seconds_screenon2 = 0;
  seconds_screenoff2 = 0;
 } else {
  diffrence = (seconds_screenoff2) - (seconds_screenon2);
  seconds_screenon2 = 0;
  seconds_screenoff2 = 0;
 }

 return diffrence;
}

}
```

---

manifest.xml

```
<receiver android:name=".MyReceiver" >
   <intent-filter>
     <action android:name="android.intent.action.ACTION_SHUTDOWN" >
     </action>
   </intent-filter>
</receiver>

<service
   android:name=".MyService"
   android:exported="false" />
```

paste it in `application` tag

---

*its works fine for me* **in background too**

Comment: What is .MyReceiver & .MyService? as I know those are acitivity name....

Comment: @AtiarTalukdar `MyReceiver` is [BroadcastReceiver](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html)  & `MyService` is [Service class](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html)

Comment: this is not working in my code. could you please give me a complete code? I need it urgently. I mean need to implement power button or volume buttom double press action in lockscreen or others screen.

Comment: getting error over here...

seconds_screenon = 0 L;

Answer (score 1):

Check this : [Power Button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6848518/detect-on-off-key-press-android)

and this : [Press Power Button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21386629/detecting-three-presses-of-power-button?rq=1)

```
static int i=0;
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if (event.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_POWER) {
       i++;
        if(i==2){
    //do something

//at the end again i=0;
        }

    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

Comment: where should i give this code since I dont have any activity in this application. Only broadcast Receiver class alone

Comment: Its working only when my app is in active.But I want it to be done even if I'm out of my app

Comment: Did you add a reciever in the manifest? Like this : <receiver android:name=".MyBroadCastReciever">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.SCREEN_OFF"/>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.SCREEN_ON"/>
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>

Answer (score 1):

Try this...

```
public boolean onKeyDown(int code, KeyEvent keyEvent) {
        if (keyEvent.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_POWER) {

            // Your Logic Is Here
            return true;
        }
        return super.onKeyDown(code, keyEvent);
    }
```